# Salesforce Lightning WebPage Rendering

Tags: lightning, ui, test-automation

Im a Test Automation Engineer. I was analyzing an application built using Salesforce Lightning. I tried to identify an element (Image) in DOM using a tool. I observed that the tool identified the DOM element 4 or 5 seconds before it got rendered on the browser. I used Chrome Dev Tools and used the Network tab to see when the particualr DOM resource (Image) is getting queued for download. It was very close to the rendering time.

Hence, I would like to understand how web page rendering works in Salesforce lighting. Is there a way to identify whether the particular object is completely rendered on the screen by the browser?

Request some explanation or share some documentation.

Comment: did you try playing with the lightning chrome extension: [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en) - this would give you more inspection tools